# Eclipse Workspace problems over Microsoft OneDrive

Tags: eclipse, onedrive

I recently migrated a number of Eclipse workspaces from a network drive to OneDrive in order to simplify accessing my projects across devices. These workspaces originated from my Windows 7 system, and when I access these workspaces on that system, everything works fine. However, when I access them from my Windows 8.1 laptop on OneDrive, Eclipse gives me an "Internal Error" which states "The folder '..\..\.metadata' is read-only." 
 So my question is: how do I remedy this situation? Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure, but are the contents of that folder available offline (you can see this in the Windows Explorer when you are in that folder).

My guess is that Eclipse is having problems with the virtual files that show on disk but aren't actually there because they haven't been downloaded from the service. If you right click on the folder you can choose "Make available offline" and force all the files to be downloaded to your computer. Once they're all local, I bet Eclipse will be happier.