# Eclipse can't find the DTD for my XML file in the same location, only on Desktop

Tags: xml, windows, eclipse, dtd, file-location

I have to create a DTD referenced by an XML file for class using Eclipse (i'm on Version 2022-09). I put the DTD in the same file location as the XML. The workspace navigator can find it without problems. But when referencing it in the XML, Eclipse shows me an Error saying it can't find the file.
[image: this is the code]

Since I use both a PC at home and a Laptop for class, I have everything we do in class saved in a separate workspace. That workspace is located in my Documents Folder (using Windows 10 for OneNote notetaking), because I have not yet found out how to back up a folder in OneDrive that is not either Documents, Pictures or my Desktop and I want to be able to access everything on my PC as well. This may be the reason Eclipse can't find the DTD.

I tried copying the file path of the DTD, but Eclipse still was unable to find it. Because the file path looks like this:

```
C:\Users\(my username)\OneDrive\المستندات\Uni
```

I figured Eclipse can't read the symbols. When I put a copy of the DTD on my Desktop, Eclipse was able to find it without problems. (I don't back up my Desktop so the file path does not include OneDrive).

It is however really impractical to have to put a new copy on the desktop every time I change something in the DTD. Using a shortcut did not work either. So I wanted to ask if there was a workaround to that problem anyone knew of, like changing the encoding to something that can read those Symbols if that exists.

Comment: The DTD and XML file should be on the project classpath and having workspace on the cloud or a network share it's not a good idea. You could try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23483074/2834978

Comment: Both files are on the classpath, i specified them to be sure. The whole Folder is set to be always available. Why is having a workspace on the cloud a bad idea? Sorry, i'm pretty new to this.

Comment: files over a network can be affected behind the scenes making it unstable I think.